# Disable Adobe Sign-in - Acrobat DC

Tags: adobe-acrobat, windows-installer

I've packaged an install for Acrobat DC using the Creative Cloud Packager, everything installs correctly but during testing I noticed that every time I launch Acrobat DC or open a PDF a window will pop-up asking for Adobe Sign-In.  This is kind of annoying and I haven't yet found a way to disable it.

It looks like this:
[image]

I've tried the Acrobat Customization Wizard DC and don't see any options for disabling the sign-in screen. I've also tried a few registry entries.

I'm sure there has to be an MSI property I'm just not aware of.

Comment: If you sign in your account.  What happens after you open it a second time?

Comment: If I sign in, it's fine. If I just hit the close button it's okay as well, but will prompt the next time it's open. The issue is, it don't want it to prompt at all. Not all users are going to have a login and this is essentially a nag-screen anyway.  I know that it's been possible to disable in the past.

Comment: Well Adobe DC was recently released, so I thought, perhaps this nag screen was actually new.  Sounds like its a screen because of your CC subscription.  If it wasn't the new version I could attempt to figure it out but don't have my copy yet.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to look in to whether it's something wrong with my CC subscription in a bit. I'll update with more information then.

Comment: SO, it looks like this prompt goes away if I install another Adobe CC product along side Acrobat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ultimately [fixed](https://adminfix.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/disable-adobe-sign-in-prompt-acrobat-pro-dc/) the Adobe Sign In pop-up issue by **creating a license file package** with [Adobe Creative Cloud Packager](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/packager.html) and applying that after installing the Acrobat DC package.

This doesn't seem necessary with the other Creative Cloud products from what I can see.

[image]

Create the license file package and save it to a location.

[image]

Then enter the key and build the package.

[image]

After installation of Acrobat DC, you can run the `AdobeSerialization.exe` program located inside the License File folder created earlier to properly license Acrobat Pro DC.

Comment: Perfect, your answer was my light in the dark woods of Adobe Deployment software!

Comment: Josh - Is this your site: https://adminfix.wordpress.com/? Good stuff regardless but keep up the good work and putting information out there for people. I've not done the WSUS 4.0 yet but that SQL process seems slick and for you to get that documented with such great too... great job to you and/or anyone contributing. Wanted to reward you a bit for your work too so I hope you don't mind. kudos

Comment: Yeah, it's mine. I try to document any things I do where the information exists out there, but maybe isn't all in one place.  I don't update too much unfortunately.